# Connect to remote Oracle Database

Tags: database, oracle, qt, remote-server

I needed to make an application connect with a oracle database located in the same network (ping the host works fine), but not in the same machine (i.e. an remote server). I developed then a software using Qt and I was able to connect it successfully with that database from my machine, but I'm not being able to do it from the machine my software is supposed to be located during its functioning. I've tried to understand what is so special about my machine that on it my software is able to connect with the Oracle database while it's not able to do the same in the right machine, and it seems that the only different thing is that I've installed the Oracle database here, while I'm not allowed to do the same there.

The error returned by Qt is that I'm simply unable to logon, while the QOCIDriver returns that it wasn't possible to create the environment. Interestingly enough, the same problem was occurring with me on my machine during the time I didn't have the Oracle database installed and neither the Oracle Client something. And this Oracle Client something is already installed in the official machine with no positive results.

So I'ld like to know exactly what I need to do to make my software works. Install the database after all in the official machine? Not viable. Install the Oracle Client? I've already done it. Add the ORACLE_HOME registry/environment variable? Did both. ^^ Copied the dbhome_1/BIN folder with lots of dlls and .exe to the official machine? Did it already, and that only made it began to crash while trying to connect to the database. And now I'm out of solutions...

I'm glad for any help!

Momergil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of trying, finally I was able to solve my problem.

Essentially I had to copy the Oracle database installer to the official computer and active the Oracle Universal Installer choosing the option "Install only the database softwares", i.e., not the database itself. After that, it run fine.